# Why using Xor operator to swap objects in selection sort doesn't't work?

Tags: c++, selection-sort

I have this simple example that implements select sort algorithm:

```
int main(){

    vector<int> vi{ 5, 7, 23, 7, 23, 5, 
    77, 10, 57, 23,  2  };
    int min = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < vi.size() - 1; ++i){
        min = i;
        for(int j = i + 1; j < vi.size(); ++j){
            if(vi[j] < vi[min]){
                min = j;
            }
        }
            vi[i] ^= vi[min];
            vi[min] ^= vi[i];
            vi[i] ^= vi[min];
     //int tmp = vi[i];
            //vi[i] = vi[min];
            //vi[min] = tmp;
    }

    for(auto i : vi)
        cout << i << ", ";
    cout << endl;

    cout << endl;
}
```

The problem is when using a temporary object to swap values works fine but using Xor operator I get wrong results!!

Here is the output of using Xor operator:

```
2, 5, 5, 0, 7, 10, 23, 23, 23, 57, 77,
```

And here is the correct result using a temporary object:

```
2, 5, 5, 7, 7, 10, 23, 23, 23, 57, 77,
```

Comment: [never ever use XOR swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm#Reasons_for_avoidance_in_practice)

Comment: You might want to take a look at [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) and then ditch the usage of your custom swap.

Comment: See also [std::iter_swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap)

Comment: @phuclv: The arguments against which you linked are quite weak.  At best you can conclude "avoid unless you have a good reason", but don't ignore the reasons wikipedia gives in favor.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'd consider it mentioning it being "opaque" to be the major argument. After all, readability is key, and if the more readable version has no drawbacks (time and memory), it is clearly superior (without the usage `std::swap` and instead using a temporary variable as alterantive to XOR swap, we have a disadvantage there, granted).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

when `i == min` you get:

```
        vi[i] ^= vi[i];
        vi[i] ^= vi[i];
        vi[i] ^= vi[i];
```

which is the same as

```
        vi[i] = 0;
```

just less readable, less efficient, and not as general as swap, which always work.

You should use

```
std::swap(vi[i], vi[min]);
```

Comment: Ok now  Thank you!